# Select following-sibling if element unknown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath

I want to select the first sibling of a tag from an HTML element. Lets say I want to get the `<a>` that follows this `<span>`:

```
<span id="unique"></span>
<a href="#">
```

This can easily be done with the following Xpath:

```
//div[@id="unique"]/following-sibling::a
```

This, however, is very specific in a way that it looks for an `<a>` tag. How can I make it more generic that it would find any tag as long as it is the first sibling to the element I selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write as below

```
//span[@id="unique"]/following-sibling::*[1]
```

Here is a sample HTML :

```html
<div>
    <span id="unique"></span>
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>bar</p>
</div>
```

`XPATH` expression:

```xpath
//span[@id="unique"]/following-sibling::*[1]
```

*output*

```
<p>foo</p>
```